# How can I use C++ copy for reverse elements?

Tags: c++, c++17

I want to reverse the elements in vector, so I use reverse function and copy function. reverse function act well but copy function got wrong result.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include "show.h"


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
    std::list<int> s = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
    
    std::copy(v.rbegin(), v.rend(), v.begin());

    show(v); // expected result: 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
                 // result: 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
 
    return 0;
}
```

what's the problem with my code?

Comment: You have overlapping source and destination ranges, see example of the `std::copy` implementation at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy. If you need to reverse, use `std::reverse`.

Comment: What is `s` for?

Comment: Must the source and destination vector be the same? Do you just need the source vector reversed or do you just want a copy of the reversed range in a new vector?

Comment: If you only want to show the reverse do you actually have to reverse the content? You can use `for(const int value : v | std::views::reverse())` (C++20), or you can use the the rbegin and rend when printing the characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what's the problem with my code?

Because it's reading and writing from the same vector. It's reading from one side, and writing from the other side.

When the two sides meet in the middle, the reading side continues to read what was already written from the other side. Hilarity ensues.

Your expected results would be as if the original, pristine contents of the vector get read from start to finish. But you seem to be forgetting that, as the vector gets read, the other end of the vector starts to get immediately overwritten by the writing side of the copy.

That's the problem with your code.